# Playsound do Python não está reproduzindo um áudio

Tags: python

**Criei um programa que ele sintetiza uma fala em Python com a biblioteca gTTS, mas no final quando vou reproduzir o áudio salvo aparece este erro:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/vinic/Desktop/Programação/Projetos/Lia/Lia/Lia.py", line 4, in <module>
    Falar("Bom dia")
    File "C:\Users\vinic\Desktop\Programação\Projetos\Lia\Lia\Habilidades\Falar.py", line 15, in Falar
    playsound.playsound("C:\\Users\\vinic\\Desktop\\Programação\\Projetos\\Lia\\Lia\\Sons\\Fala.mp3")
    File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
    winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
    File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 24: invalid continuation byte
```

**Programa**

```
    from Subprogramas.BarraDiretorio import BarraDiretorio
    from gtts import gTTS
    import playsound
    import os

    def Falar(Texto):

    Barra = BarraDiretorio()

    Diretorio = os.getcwd().replace('Habilidades', 'Sons')

    Sintese = gTTS(Texto, lang='pt', slow=False)
    Sintese.save(Diretorio + '{}Fala.mp3'.format(Barra))

    playsound.playsound("C:\\Users\\vinic\\Desktop\\Programação\\Projetos\\Lia\\Lia\\Sons\\Fala.mp3")
```

**Se alguém souber de algo por favor me fale :)**

Comment: `from Subprogramas.BarraDiretorio import BarraDiretorio` - O que é isso?

Comment: Que texto você pediu para ele falar?

Comment: **from Subprogramas.BarraDiretorio import BarraDiretorio**  É uma função que criei para pegar o sistema operacional do usuário e retornar uma barra (  \ ou /  )

Comment: E o texto é passado como entrada da função **Falar( )**

Answer (score 1):

Para mim, isso funcionou perfeitamente:

```py
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound
import os

def falar(texto):
    sintese = gTTS(texto, lang='pt', slow=False)
    arq = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'fala.mp3')
    sintese.save(arq)
    playsound.playsound(arq)

falar("Boa tarde. Ei, como você está?")
```

Só precisei dar o `pip install gtts` e o `pip install playsound` antes de executar.

Comment: Estranho, copiei e colei, mas ainda retorna o mesmo erro

Answer (score 1):

Acho que achei o problema, **provavelmente era o diretório** que estava usando. Nele tinha uma pasta chamada "Programação", e talvez o playsound **não aceite acentuações no caminho**, porque mudei para "Programacao" e deu certo.

Comment: O bug está dentro da biblioteca playsound aqui: https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/blob/master/playsound.py#L23